# If statement not working inside ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this html code

```
<div class="vote">
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="1" class="vote-arrow vote-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>
    <div class="total-vote">0</div>
    <div data-post-id="@item.PostId" data-vote-rank="-1" class="vote-arrow vote-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></div>
</div>
```

And this jQuery ajax post

```
$(".vote-arrow").click(function () {
    var postId = $(this).data("post-id");
    var voteRank = $(this).data("vote-rank");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Posts/Vote/",
        data: { postId: postId, voteRank: voteRank },
        context: this,
        success: function () {
            console.log(voteRank); //working, I get 1
            if (voteRank === "1") {
                console.log(voteRank); //nothing in the console
                $(this).css({ 'color': 'red' });
            }
            alert("working");
        }
    });
});
```

If-statement in the `success` is not working.

If I press the div with `data-vote-rank="1"` I get 1 in the console from the `console.log` outside the if-statement and the `alert` after the if-statement. voteRank in the if-statement condition is one if I debug but I don't get the console.log inside the if-statement (and of course not color change).

What is wrong?

Comment: Either use `==` or `voteRank === 1`, the identity (`===`) operator also check type, they must match to be considered equal

Comment: I think it's more likely that the condition is correctly evaluated and simply does not match your expectation, rather than that the condition is incorrectly evaluated.

Comment: When you debug, what's the value of "voteRank" ?  Is it `1` or is it `"1"` ?   It depends on how you *set* the data prop, because it will keep the data type, ie it's most likely it's `1` (the number) which **does not** === "1" text, but **does** == "1".  ie, what @Satpal said.

Comment: When you take value of custom attribute like $(..).data('..') and if value of that custom attribute is Boolean or number then you get it as Boolean or number not as string .

Comment: is the voterank return Int or String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `==` or `voteRank === 1`, the identity (`===`) operator also check type, they must match to be considered equal.

The [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) internally convert value in to appropriate data-type. They are not string. `1 === "1"` will evaluate to `false`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will convert the data attribute to a number in this case. From the [documentation on .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is converted to the number 100.

You should change the condition of your if statement to reflect this:

```
 if (voteRank === 1) {
    // snip
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert the result to int. 
you can use parseInt() before applying the value to "if" condition.

```
$(".vote-arrow").click(function () {
    var postId = $(this).data("post-id");
    var voteRank = $(this).data("vote-rank");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Posts/Vote/",
        data: { postId: postId, voteRank: voteRank },
        context: this,
        success: function () {
            console.log(voteRank); //working, I get 1
            if (parseInt(voteRank) === 1) {
                console.log(voteRank); //nothing in the console
                $(this).css({ 'color': 'red' });
            }
            alert("working");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

So before using it convert the left side variable type to same as that of the right. In Ur Solution Convert the voteRank to int

```
voteRank = parseInt(voteRank, 10);
```

then check

```
if (voteRank) === 1) {

            }
```